# In a 2-column Bootstrap row, how do I get the right-column (which has a background image) to always be the same size as the left column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap page begins with a single row with two columns. In the first column there is some text content that varies in size. The right column will have a background image and the text in that column will always be about the same size. I want the right column to stretch to always be the same height as the left column and to also stretch when the user resizes the window so much that the right column becomes its own row beneath the left column. May I ask how to do this?

Comment: Flexbox is the keyword here

Comment: bootstrap4 https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/ & see https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/  library: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css  Questions about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 3 and you don't want to use flexbox or Bootstrap 4, have a look here:

http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

It's pretty robust, just add classes for the row and desired columns (I usually use `row-md-height` and `col-md-height`, for smartphones it's usually not needed.